# Simple php calculator with form validation

Tags: php, validation

Today i wrote a simple calculator but i have a problem with form validation. I do perform validation as i want calculator to calculate numbers, not objects or arrays, etc. When i perform validation input can't be validated as a number because php gives me warning about strings being passed, not a numbers, no matter what i input.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$A = trim(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'A', 'FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT')));
$B = trim(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'B', 'FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT')));
$operation = trim(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'operation', 'FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING')));
    if(isset($A) && isset($B) && isset($operation)){
      if(!is_numeric($A) || !is_numeric($B)){
        echo "Invalid parameters.";
      }
      else{
        if($operation == 'plus'){
          echo "$A + $B = ", $A + $B;
        }
        else if($operation == 'minus'){
          echo "$A - $B = ", $A - $B;
        }
        else if($operation == 'multiplication'){
          echo "$A * $B = ", $A * $B;
        }
        else if($operation == 'division'){
          echo "$A / $B = ", $A / $B;
        }
        else{
          echo "Invalid operator.";
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "No operators.";
    }
    ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name='form1' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method='get'>
      <div>
        <p>argument 1 <input type='text' name='A'></p>
        + <input type='radio' name='operation' value='plus' checked='checked'>
        - <input type='radio' name='operation' value='minus'>
        * <input type='radio' name='operation' value='multiplication'>
        / <input type='radio' name='operation' value='division'>
        <p>argument 2 <input type='text' name='B'></p>
        <input type='submit' value="Calculate">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are warning messages which i get when i open file in browser:
Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in ./file.php on line 3

Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in ./file.php on line 4

Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in ./file.php on line 5
Invalid parameters.

Also i got interesting thing about filter input. When i write: FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING without " ' " then i'm getting additional warning:
Warning: Use of undefined constant FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING - assumed 'FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in ./file.php on line 4
Same goes to filter_validate_float.

What am i doing wrong and what should i improve in this form validation?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING` are constants, meaning they should not be quoted. Quoting them makes them strings.

Comment: @JayBlanchard actually, `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING` is not a valid constant. What exactly would it be filtering for because technically anything would be valid as a string. @OP Typically you would validate the content of the string like email, ip address, etc. http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php. Also, the `trim` and `strip_tags` calls are useless. The filter function would return false if filter failed or a valid float value. Neither of which can have spaces or html. You are just converting your float back into a string.

Comment: My bad @JonathanKuhn, just going off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you say, your code *should* be correct.
PHP converts strings to numbers when possible so it should be able to multiply. Warnings are not actual problems. IE, if you call a variable that isn't set, it will give you a warning that the variable wasn't defined. You shouldn't need to do a filter_var in this case. Truth is, you want to prevent it working if the variables are not number but it already won't work. You cannot get *true* number imputs from your form, even if you put a numeric imput type as it will be considered by default as flat text. What you could do however if you want to improve to make sure only numbers *should* be entered, you can change your text input to :

`<input type='number' name='B' />`

This will make sure numbers are typed. However, it doesn't prevent URL injections.

If you have any other question, let me know in comments :)

Comment: You missed something really important. `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING` are constants, meaning they should not be quoted. Quoting them makes them strings.

Comment: Good practice says superglobal arrays shouldn't be accessible directly and they should have always be filtered in some way, in this case it is $_GET. Workaround with input type number would be nice if it could get float numbers but it takes only integers and about it webbrowser shows message instantly.